# Bracket matcing plugin in generated by xtext

Tags: xtext

How do you match brackets in the eclipse plug-in generated in a xtext project?

When the cursor is over the open or close bracket the matching bracket is highlighted.

Answer (score 0):

The eclipse editor support the matching functionality, just enable the option under the preference menu.